# Z Offset for Mapbox labels

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a 5-floor indoor building on top of a Streets Style map in Mapbox Studio Style editor. It looks almost ok in 3D, all extruded poygons and lines are at the right base height and height with about 3m space betwee the floors.

But I cannot find any base hieght or z-offset option for Symbol types in order to show labels correctly at the place where they should be in 3D. Is there a z offset for labels at all?

Comment: I'm not sure why this gets a downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently possible, but has been discussed as a possible enhancement: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/3993